# What is the complexity of these functions?

Tags: complexity-theory

Is the complexity of these functions linear e.g. O(n). I think the first two are linear

1. n+3
2. 2n+3
3. (2+(1/2(n+3))+(1/2(2n+3)))

Comment: What is x? is it related to n? Or is that times?

Comment: Use the associativity to remove the parentheses and you will see the result more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all are linear
any constants can be disregarded, and constant coefficients 2n is O(n)
for 3. it would be 1/2n+1/2n which can be disregarded, so it should be all O(n)

Comment: Unless you have a log n, a 2^n n*n or n^n it will be generally linear

Comment: For the last function, if 4 replaced both 1/2's, would it still be linear

Comment: Yes, you can ignore any constant in general, consider n=infinity, 4*infinity < infinity^2.  Four is insignificant